# What is the best way to implement pagination in web?

Tags: wordpress, web, pagination

Recently, I am developing a self-using blogging system, but I have some questions about the implementation of pagination.

The pagination I want is :

1. 10 results per page
2. When user visits the home page(/), he/she could see the current page he/she is at(in this example is page one), and if there are more than 10 results, then he/she could be able to see the 'Next' Link.
3. If there are some results before this page, and there are also some results after this page, then this page should have 'Prev' and 'Next' Link and the current page number.

This thinking appeared when I was designing the algorithm about pagination:

If I want to implement this functionality, I need to know the total numbers of published posts.(If it is not published, it shouldn't be displayed), so maybe I need to write this SQL code :

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post WHERE published IS NOT TRUE;
```

And I could pick the result above and the current page number the user is at to compute the pagination result.

But the question I want to ask is if there are many records , performance will be very terrible, how could I make this program more faster?

I see the pagination of a blog that has thousands of post and is built on top of WordPress is very fast, I want to know how could I archive this speed ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why would you assume that "if there are many records , performance will be very terrible"? Just make sure you get only your page records from the database and it will work just fine.

Comment: Do you mean count is so fast that I don't need to worry about that?

Answer (score 0):

go through this sample [PHP Pagination](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html) coding. Results won't be slow because of the `LIMIT n,n+RecordsPerPage` part of the mySQL query.

Comment: Thank you. I have came up a solution to this problem. My solution is creating a table for caching the total numbers of published posts. And whenever I want to get this number, what I need to do is just fetching the result from this table.